# No socket timeout although it is set

Tags: java, sockets, axis

I have an interesting question regarding sockets:

In our company, we have two internet connections, when one stops working, then the other one kicks in.
However, if at that time one of our internal applications is communicating with other service (axis) the thread hangs indefinetely on `Socket.read()` and is not timeouted, although its set!

```
binding.setTimeout(ResourceManager.getConfiguration().getInteger("general.defaultTimeout"));
```

I've been told that its not timeouted because the data are still sent to the service im making call to though new path, but because its tcp the service is rejecting those packets in a way that doesn't make client know about it (so it is retrying it, thus not timeouting).

I'd like someone to verify and elaborate on that. It just seems weird to me that socket wouldnt timeout after some time if it is trying to send something withour any result. Is there any way/setting to set socket so that its not hanging like that, or I just have to implement some client-side timeouting?

Comment: What is binding? Which Class it belongs to?

Comment: binding is soap stub im using to access other service